# how do you combine two large vectors of different sizes into a single tibble?

Tags: r

I have two vectors, x and y, of different lengths. I want a tibble where every value of x is repeated for every value of y.

```
x <- c("a", "b") 
y <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

example tibble:

```
x   y
a   1           
a   2           
a   3           
b   1           
b   2           
b   3
```

Comment: `expand.grid(x, y)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `expand.grid(x,y)`.

```
> expand.grid(x,y)
  Var1 Var2
1    a    1
2    b    1
3    a    2
4    b    2
5    a    3
6    b    3
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work for me. But expand_grid() did work. But thank you!

Comment: It's a good solution as well.